# Why rpm -q vnc-server return not installed after apparent succesful installation

Tags: rpm

```
root@host [/tmp]#  yum install vnc-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * extras: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Package tigervnc-server-module-1.0.90-0.17.20110314svn4359.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Yet when I run `rpm -q vnc-server` I get:

```
root@host [/tmp]# rpm -q vnc-server
package vnc-server is not installed
root@host [/tmp]#
```

I am following instruction here

Comment: I hope you should first run the following and check if the package is available in you repo configured on your server 
yum search vnc-server
tigervnc-server.x86_64 : A TigerVNC server
tigervnc-server-applet.noarch : Java TigerVNC viewer applet for TigerVNC server
tigervnc-server-module.x86_64 : TigerVNC module to Xorg

you should get something like this out put then go ahead and install  with "yum install tigervnc-server.x86_64" . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RPM packages have a way of indicating what exactly they provide as part of their installation. These "provides" are usually calculated automatically, but can also be added manually by the packager. Usually, this is done in order to satisfy generic dependencies -- for example, some packages may require a way to send mail, but they don't really care whether you run postfix, sendmail, exim, or whatever. To solve this problem, packages that provide mail transport capabilities have a generic "Provides: MTA".

You can check on your system:

```
yum provides MTA
```

You will see that this returns exim, postfix, and sendmail. When multiple packages provide a generic functionality such as "vnc server", they can include that as part of their "manual provides." In our case:

```
yum provides vnc-server
```

This will return several hits, of which tigervnc-server is one.

You can list all "provides" in a package by using `rpm -q --provides`. E.g.:

```
# rpm -q --provides tigervnc-server
config(tigervnc-server) = 1.1.0-6.1.fc17
tightvnc-server = 1.5.0-0.15.20090204svn3586
vnc-libs = 4.1.3-2
vnc-server = 4.1.3-2
tigervnc-server = 1.1.0-6.1.fc17
tigervnc-server(x86-64) = 1.1.0-6.1.fc17
```

Answer (score 3):

`vnc-server` is not the actual package name, but an alias for `tigervnc-server-module` (which yum says is already installed). I do not know exactly where this alias is defined, but I assume it is a yum repository thing that the rpm program does not know anything about.

Comment: It's included as part of manual "provides" for an RPM package. Check with `rpm -q --provides tigervnc-server`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[root@dunno ~]# yum list vnc\*
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin,         subscription-manager, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Available Packages
vnc-ltsp-config.noarch                                                                      4.0-7.fc12                                                                        fedora
vnc-reflector.i686                                                                     1.2.4-7.fc12                                                                      fedora
vnc2swf.x86_64                                                                         0.5.0-2.el6.rf                                                                    rpmforge
vncreflector.x86_64                                                                    1.2.4-0.2.el6.rf                                                                  rpmforge


[root@dunno ~]# yum list tiger\*
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin,  subscription-manager, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Installed Packages
tigervnc.x86_64                                                1.0.90-        0.15.20110314svn4359.el6_1.1                                  @production-rhel-x86_64-            workstation-6
tigervnc-server.x86_64                                         1.0.90-  0.15.20110314svn4359.el6_1.1                                  @production-rhel-x86_64-     workstation-6
 Available Packages
 tiger.i686                                                     3.2.1-11.fc12                                                          fedora
 tigervnc.i686                                                  1.0.90-  0.8.20100219svn3993.fc13                                      fedora
tigervnc.x86_64                                                1.0.90-0.17.20110314svn4359.el6                                      production-rhel-x86_64-  workstation-6
 tigervnc-server.i686                                           1.0.90-  0.8.20100219svn3993.fc13                                      fedora
tigervnc-server.x86_64                                         1.0.90-0.17.20110314svn4359.el6                                      production-rhel-x86_64-  workstation-6
 tigervnc-server-applet.noarch                                  1.0.90-  0.17.20110314svn4359.el6                                      production-rhel-x86_64-  workstation-optional-6
 tigervnc-server-module.i686                                    1.0.90-0.8.20100219svn3993.fc13                                      fedora
 tigervnc-server-module.x86_64                                  1.0.90- 0.17.20110314svn4359.el6                                      production-rh
```

So, you need to do this.

```
yum install -y tigervnc.x86_64
```

Comment: Darn, I can't get the formatting correct

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Why do I have to do yum install -y tigervnc.x86_64

Comment: Erm. because it is the package name. You are asking for an installation of vnc-server and this is the package that provides it. If you do `yum info tigervnc.x86_64` you will get more information